# Need to only find the users present at the max level for each story and country

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So, I've been dealing with huge dataset and I need to find only the users who are present at the final level of each story for each country. Eg. There are 15 levels in story A in brazil so i need the users only present at level 15 for that story. In story E there are 28 levels so i need only the users present at 28th level in that story for each country.

I'm currently using this query but this fetches users for all the levels.

```
SELECT
  event,
  story,
  country,
  level,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) uniques
FROM
  `xyz`
WHERE
  (date between "2020-08-01" and "2020-08-07") 
  AND event in ("start")    
   
GROUP BY
  event,
  story,
  country,
  level
ORDER BY
  country,
  story,
  level
```

I've attached an image with dummy data, highlighting(yellow) the datapoints that needs to be fetched.

With ref to the image: In story A, at Level 15(max) in Brazil 1970 users and in UK 81 users and in US 301 users should be the only output.

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `where level = 28`.

Comment: The issue here is that the levels are dynamic across each story.

Comment: Are you using BigQuery or MySQL?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm using BigQuery with standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the maximum story *per* country/story, then use window functions:

```
SELECT event, story, country, level, COUNT(DISTINCT id) as uniques
FROM (SELECT x.*, MAX(level) OVER (PARTITION BY story, country) as max_level
      FROM `xyz` x
      WHERE date between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-07') AND
            event in ('start')    
     ) x
WHERE level = max_level   
GROUP BY event, story, country, level
ORDER BY country, story, level
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I used CTE to form the xyz table and used this query. It worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative version for BigQuery Standard SQL - just wrap your initial query with "little extra"

```
#standardSQL
SELECT event, story, country, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(level, uniques) ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT event, story, country, level, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS uniques
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-07'
  AND event IN ('start')    
  GROUP BY event, story, country, level
) 
GROUP BY event, story, country
```

when applied to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row event   story   country level   uniques  
1   start   A       B       15      2    
2   start   E       B       28      1
```

Comment: This is great! Works like a charm. Just a slight modification to the initial query :)